# Como traduzir "cafuné" para o inglês?

Tags: tradução

> **cafuné**
>   carícia em geral, esp. com a ponta dos dedos no couro cabeludo de outrem; afago, mimo.

Desconheço o uso dessa palavra no português de Portugal, porém é bastante usada no Brasil.

Qual seria uma boa tradução da palavra para o inglês?

Comment: A palavra "cafuné" é reconhecida e usada em Portugal, mas não tão usada como no Brasil.

Comment: Cafuné parece ter origem kimbunda/luanda. Imagino que em Angola esse termo tenha o sentido mais lato do que o adquirido pelos outros falares portugueses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa questão foi respondida no english.stackexchange, na [One word equivalent to “play with someone's hair”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285964/one-word-equivalent-to-play-with-someones-hair). Irei traduzir as melhores respostas aqui.

### [Resposta de A.P.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285964/one-word-equivalent-to-play-with-someones-hair/285966#285966), a aceita pelo criador da pergunta

> Eu não acho que dê para usar uma palavra que denote "brincar com os cabelos de alguém", mas acho que o verbo "*to caress*" faz um bom trabalho em expressar a ideia dele acariciar amavelmente os cabelos dela:
>
> > Her head was in his lap, and he was caressing her hair.
> >
> > (*A cabeça dela estava no colo dele, enquanto ele fazia cafuné nela.*)
>
> Definição:
>
> > caress: Tocar alguém gentilmente mostrando-lhe amor.

(Ver definição no dicionário [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/caress))

### [Resposta de Elian](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/285971/250563), a mais votada

> Considere **fondle**.
>
> > : manusear, acariciar ou tocar amavelmente

(Ver definição no dicionário [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fondle))

### Comentário final

Particularmente, creio que *fondle* e *caress* sejam traduções válidas. Porém note que elas (principalmente "fondle") são usadas bastante em sentido sexual, principalmente para se referir ao ato de manusear e brincar com o seio de uma mulher.

Comment: Eu não encontrei muito uso moderno do verbo *to fondle* que não fosse o sentido sexual (uma pesquisa rápida no youtube ou google images espelha isso), imagino que atualmente essa palavra não seja usada para o sentido semelhante a cafuné, tal como foi no passado. Quanto a *to caress*, os resultados sexuais nas pesquisas são bem menos frequentes.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de não ser uma traducão precisa, **cuddling** pode ser uma opcão conforme o contexto.

> [Cuddle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cuddle?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)
>
> > to hold close in an affectionate manner; hug tenderly; fondle.

Caso você esteja mais interessado em carícias/mimos, *Cuddling* é uma boa opcão.

Comment: Cuddle parece mais genérico ainda. Cafuné, acredito que seja mais ligado a carícias na cabeça ou cabelo. Cuddle ficaria mais perto de uma carícia.

Answer (score -1):

Considere a expressão *"to run the fingers through  hair"*, que significa *"percorrer os dedos pelos cabelos de "*. Por exemplo:

> Running your fingers through your lover's hair.
>
> (Percorrer seus dedos pelos cabelos de sua amada.)

Comment: Welcome Shoyu, the question was asked in Portuguese, for all we can tell the OP might not even understand your answer. Would you mind translating it to Portuguese?